# One definite integral-multiple answers?

Tags: calculus, integration

So I came across the integral

$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{1+x^2}\, dx$

Now the conventional way is to solve this via trigonometric substitution, and you get the answer as $tan^{-1} x + C$.

However, using some stuff I learnt somewhere else, I tried to play around with the integral a bit.

I first took $dx$ as $\frac{1}{2} d(x^2)$, as we know that $d(x^2)=$<s>2 dx</s> $2x dx$

Then, I pushed the 1 in, so I got $dx=\frac{1}{2x} d(1+x^2)$, as $d(1)$ is obviously 0.

Then, I substituted this into the original integral:

$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{1+x^2}\, \frac{1}{2x} d(1+x^2)$

$=\displaystyle\frac{1}2  \int \frac{1}{x(1+x^2)}\, d(1+x^2)$

<s>And this gives me 1/2 ln|1+x^2| +C, which seems entirely different from the result that we use commonly.</s>

Wolfram alpha reports the answer to be $\frac{ln x}2 - \frac{ln (1+x^2)}4+C$

Now I know that if I leave it as an indefinite integral, the C makes up for the difference.

But what if I take a definite integral?

If I integrate from $x=1$ to $x=2$,

Using $tan^{-1} x$: $tan^{-1} (2) - tan^{-1} (1)= 0.321750554 $

<s>Using\frac{1}2 ln|1+x^2|$: $\frac{1}2 (ln|1+2^2|-ln|1+1^2|)=\frac{1}2(ln|5|-ln|2|)=0.45814536593</s>

Using $\frac{ln x}2 - \frac{ln (1+x^2)}4$: Wolfram Alpha gives $\frac{1}4 ln(\frac{8}5)$ = 0.1175...

Have I erred somewhere? I'm extremely sorry if I've made an extremely stupid mistake somewhere in here.

Thank you!

Comment: $d(1+x^2) = 2x dx$.

Comment: @PierreCarre Oops, that was extremely silly of me. If I substitute $dx=\frac{1}{2x} d(1+x^2)$, will it work out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Typesetting tip:  If you type `$\tan x$`, you will obtain $\tan x$.  If you type `$\ln x$`, you will obtain $\ln x$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig so that formatting gives the non-italicised versions?

Comment: That is correct.  Similarly, you can use `$\sin x$`, `$\cos x$`, `$\csc x$`, `$\sec x$`, `$\cot x$`, `$\arcsin x$`, `$\arccos x$`, `$\arctan x$`, and `$\log x$` to obtain, respectively, $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, $\cot x$, $\arcsin x$, $\arccos x$, and $\arctan x$.  Doing so distinguishes the functions from the variables.

Comment: Notice if you take the derivative of $\frac{\ln x}{2} - \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{2} + C$, you do not get $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. (The commands like `$\tan x$` etc. also make the spacing look nice, in addition to using an upright font. You can do similar formatting to any "word" with `$\operatorname{word}$`)

Comment: @aschepler Differentiating $\frac{\ln x}2 - \frac{\ln (1+x^2)}4$ gives $\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{2x}{2(1+x^2)}$ which returns the integral which I had created by manipulating some stuff. Does that mean there is a mistake in what I've done there?

Comment: And thanks a lot for the advice regarding formatting, this is the first time I'm doing this and it's a bit alien to me.

Comment: Yes, the $d(1+x^2)$ syntax is a bit irregular and may have contributed to a mistake. I think the answer by CompuChip probably explains what went wrong in those steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to decide whether to integrate over $x$ or $x^2 + 1$, you can't pick and choose.

To make this more clear, let's do a proper substitution and define $u = 1 + x^2$. Then $\mathrm du = 2x \, \mathrm dx$, so indeed, as you have already written,
$$\int \frac{1}{1 + x^2} \, \mathrm dx = \int \frac{1}{2x \, u} \,\mathrm du.$$

However, the step you missed, is that in order to properly integrate over this new variable you also need to express $x$ in terms of $u$. Since $1 + x^2 \ge 0$ we can write $x = \sqrt{u - 1}$, so you will need to calculate
$$\frac12 \int \frac{1}{u\sqrt{u - 1}} \, \mathrm du.$$

This integral is not easier to do than the original integral, but WolframAlpha still gives $2 \tan^{-1} \sqrt{u - 1} = 2 \tan^{-1} x$ as the result.

*Addendum:* If you want to calculate a definite integral (say, from $x \in [1, 2]$) don't forget to also calculate the new bounds for $u$ (in this example, $u \in [2, 5]$).

Comment: Oh so that's where I went wrong! I didn't know that you'd have to replace all the variables with your substitution. Thank you!